# Extract JSON Keys in presto, parent & child keys

Tags: sql, json, key, presto, trino

I am having an issue using prestosql, where i am trying to get all JSON keys into a single row:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': {'b1': 3, 'b2': 5}}
{'c': 3, 'a': 5}
{'d': 1, 'c': 7}
```

I tried using `map_keys`, but the result I am getting is:

```
 a, b, c, d
```

But my desired result is:

```
a, b, b1, b2, c, d
```

I am kind of stuck at this point, as I tried using `json_parse`, extract etc.

Thank you in advance

I tried `map_keys`, `json_parse/json_extract` in conjunction with map_keys

Comment: Can you please add sample data broken down in rows, desired output also broken down in rows and ideally one of the failed attempts.

Comment: Apologies, i don’t understand your ask, as my sample is the data in one row of my json column. I have tried the following code: select map_keys(cast(json_column as map(varchar,json) ) from table

Comment: That is not a valid json.

Comment: If you do `select typeof(json_column) from...`  what is the result?

Comment: Ahh, i see, apologies. I was using someone else’s example on here, as it was similar bit similar. Here is a better one - on my end it does say map(varchar,varchar) - but this is the structure: {“a”:”2”, “b”:”3”, “c”:”4”,”d”:”{“d1”:”9”,”d2”:”8”}”}  - and my desired output would be: a,b,c,d,d1,d2 (apologies, i am still learning about JSON)

Comment: When i try the method I used it only gives me a,b,c,d without d1,d2

Comment: This is the the method : array_join(map_keys(cast(json_column as map(varchar,json) )) -  forgot to include array_join

Answer (score 1):

This will not be easy and will require additional handling for every nesting level, but for 2 levels you can do the following:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(js_string) AS (
    values  (json '{"a":"2", "b":"3", "c":"4","d":{"d1":"9","d2":"8"}}')
)

-- query
select flatten(
    transform(
        map_keys(m),
        k -> coalesce(array[k] || map_keys(try_cast(m[k] as map(varchar, json))), array[k]))
    )
from (select cast(js_string as map(varchar, json)) m
      from dataset);
```

Output:

```
        _col0         
----------------------
 [a, b, c, d1, d2, d]
```

Some explanation:
basically the idea is to transform every key into array and then flatten the data, to transform the key we check if the value is actually a json object, get it's keys concatenated with current one or use the current key

- `try_cast` will return `null` if cast fails, concatenating something with null (current key) will result in null
- `coalesce` returns the first parameter if it is not null, otherwise - the second
- `flatten` - flattens array of arrays into array of elements.

P.S.

Json path syntax has an extension allowing to get keys from json object and if Trino/Presto would support it it would be quite an easy task with following path - `$..*~` (check @ https://jsonpath.com/) but currently it is not working for Trino (which already has an extended support for json path compared to Presto).